# Silverlight 5 - WCF Service Call - CompletedEvent argument e has an error

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight

I have an Silverlight application (Silverlight 5) and communicating through regular basic Service for normal operations (no database involved).

Problem:-

Before calling the service I just show the Loading (Busy Indicator control) and then calls the Service. Once it is back from the service (inside the completed event) I used to hide the Busy Indicator and performs other required operations.

In my case, Service executes all the logic successfully and returns true within max 2 minutes. But after that the logic that is placed inside the completed event is not getting executed always.

Note: Out of 3 times 2 times it works and once it fails. i.e 2 times it executes the logic perfectly and sometimes it will not do anything and just shows the progress bar. There is no pattern as such.

Also the important factor is IE7 and Chrome always works, IE8 we have this issue. Sometimes it works sometimes not. Very inconsistent !!!

I checked my code there seems to be no error and the service method on the server side is getting executed perfectly all the time.

I have cross verified the timwout parameters Client as well as Service and no problem and just to let you know I have another operation which takes around 6 minutes working fine in the same application.

Any Ideas would be highly appreciated.

Technical Details: Silverlight 5, WCF, In-Browser app, No database interactions.

Comment: Post your code, not much help without code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Wrap your service call with a "finally" to close your Busy indicator:

```
try
{
   // Notify Busy is true
   // Define Completed
       // OnCompleted
       // Notify Busy is false
   // Make Service call


}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   // Check for Timeout
   // Handle Error
}
finally
{
   // Notify Busy is false if Exception
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the direction !! It was of great help Musters.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i figured out that it was due to the service client config file's receive timeout was the one which was creating the problem. Whenever it takes more than the defined the time period it just does not come back or no response and silverlight was not throwing up that error. Increasing the ReceiveTimeout helped me to resolve this. Thanks for all your help.